# How can a kernel written in Go boot?

Tags: go, kernel

It seems most kernels are written in C. But yesterday on Hackernews there was a project called the [Biscuit research OS](https://github.com/mit-pdos/biscuit).

It claims to be written in Go although there are some assembly and C code in there. So my question is. How does something like this work where the system can boot but it's written in Go?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is asking; the pithy answer is "it boots the same way a kernel written in any other language boots" (probably, I'm no expert and haven't looked at this project). Parts of Go's runtime and standard library do depend on the operating system, so they likely had to rewrite chunks of them, but otherwise I don't see why you couldn't write an OS in Go. Maybe explaining your understanding of the boot process and why it would be limited to certain languages will help people help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look around you will find the paper(https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/papers/biscuit.pdf) they used a layer that can support Go runtime over which the Biscuit runs
[image]

It contains a lot more information in detail, I suggest you should take a look into it.